# Supporting two integer constructors with different semantics

Tags: c++, constructor, constructor-overloading

I am designing a class that has two constructors with single integer arguments that have separate semantics.

```
template <typename value_t>
class Numeric {
    value_t value_;
public:
    Numeric(value_t value) : value_(value) {}
    Numeric(long l) { /* computes value_ from l */ }
    Numeric(double d) { /* computes value_ from d */ }
    Numeric(std::string bstring) { /* computes value_ from binary string */ }
    // ...
};
```

`value_t` *must* be an integral type in this case, it could even be an alias to `long` (in which case this wouldn't even compile). Even if it wasn't a type alias to `long`, I'm not so sure how integer promotions might confuse the two constructors.

The idea is I want to support the user constructing by giving the underlying representation, *or* by giving it any possible numeric representation, which would then convert to the underlying representation (A.K.A `value_t`).

What's the best way to segregate the constructors?

Comment: The options are either define a specialization for `long` with one constructor, or change the constructor's signature. Those are the only options you have in C++.

Comment: Why don't create a function to 'compute value_ from a long' and then pass it to the class ?

Comment: @hlscalon Isn't that the point of a constructor? Take values and compute and assign members? I'm simply also trying to support direct initialization of the member.

Comment: it cannot be the job of a constructor to care about all possible conversions you can do on its parameters. If you need a `long` to construct an instance, then the constructor should take a `long`

Comment: @ktb The point of a constructor is to construct an object. It's obvious from the code that it's possible to fully construct an object using just the *result* of the transformation, so there's no requirement that you perform that calculation in a constructor. You can just require that result, and provide a way of performing the transformation should it be required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend making the constructors `private` and using instead static functions to "create" your instances. The static functions can have meaningful names, in order to explicitly tell the users what to expect from each:

```
template <typename value_t>
class Example {
    value_t value_;
    //Prevent users to directly create instances
    Example(value_t value): value_(value)
    {
    }
public:
    static Example createFromValue(value_t value)
    {
        return Example(value);
    }
    static Example createComputingValueFromLong(long l)
    {
        return Example(/*Compute from l*/l);
    }
};
```

And even if you still want to use those constructors instead of assigning the internal variable, you can put them in the private section and call them from the `static` functions, so the users will never be able to call them directly.

Comment: not being default constructible is a rather big limitation. I dont think it is worth to do that. You could get the same with a public constructor taking a `long` and a public static `createFromX` method

Comment: The OP code wasn't already default constructible, so it should not be a concern.... Anyway, yes, it could have a default constructor and other static functions to address different situations

Comment: @user463035818 And that's what I will do. There is a lot more than just an `long` constructor. The class is an numeric type and will be constructable from any possible number type (I can think of). But the `value_t` must be separate, the `createFromValue` seems like a good idea to accomplish that, like tags, but directly in the call.

Comment: I wanted to show how it could be solved using just static functions, instead of focusing only in constructors, since it seems a problem that the OP is too focused on using the constructor instead of thinking how to solve its actual problem

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Edited to take advantage of constructors, also gaining return copy elision

Comment: @LoPiTaL Now you don't even need `createFromValue`. Though it's not necessarily wrong to keep it, as it keeps users from trying to build `Example` with `long` directly, in the case where `long` is implicitly convertible to `value_t`. Edit : Though your constructor should be `explicit` to keep with the original code's intention.

Comment: @ktb "There is a lot more than just an long constructor" then maybe you should have included that in the question... i dont know, but maybe its a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Providing a constructor for each single type you want to "transform" from might be the way to go, but tbh it sounds a bit fishy

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think createFromValue is still needed, but only for the user knowing what the function will do and not having doubts about its behaviour. This of course is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly suggest you to rethink the design. Why do you need two constructors that look the same, but do two different things?

Anyhow, you could use a tag:

```
struct tag_a{};
struct tag_b{};

template <typename value_t>
class Example {
    value_t value_;
public:
    Example(value_t value, tag_a) : value_(value) {}
    Example(long l, tag_b) {  }
};
```

Usage

```
long x = 123;
auto a = Example<long>(x,tag_a());
auto b = Example<long>(x,tag_b());
```

Comment: The reason there are two different constructors is that one directly initializes the `value_` member, but the class can also convert an integer into the proper underlying representation stored in `value_`. It's likely that the `value_t` constructor will be private.

Comment: @ktb Then just don't require a tag for the public constructor.

Comment: @ktb i dont really understand your reasoning. If `value_t` has a private constructor then the second constructor of `Example` cannot work (or does it also use the initializer list? in which case i still dont see why it has to be two constructors...)

Comment: I don't see how the second constructor wouldn't work? Imagine the body is something like `value_ = l * 2`

Comment: @ktb if `value_t`s constructor is private then you cant construct the member (hence also not assign it a value in the constructors body)

Comment: @ktb with "It's likely that the value_t constructor will be private" you meant the constructor taking a `value_t` as parameter? Sorry, my misunderstanding then

Answer (score 1):

> I am designing a class that has two constructors with single integer arguments that have separate semantics.
>
> What's the best way to segregate the constructors?

---

## Your code should reflect your semantics.

---

When someone *sees* the interface of your class, they must immediately guess what its correct usage is. Since I cannot know the semantic behind your use case, I'll make my own to illustrate that.

### A simple class to handle masses

Imagine the following class to handle masses; we will enhance it to provide additional constructability:

```
template<class T>
class Mass
{
    T _kg;
public:
    Mass(T kg) : _kg(kg) {}
    T kg() const { return _kg; }
};
```

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    Mass<double> one_litter_of_water(1.0);
    std::cout << "1 L of water is: " << one_litter_of_water.kg() << " kg\n";
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d055b31923af34e).

### And now make it able to handle weird units

Now, I'd like a simple way for the user to construct a `Mass` from pounds, (or stone, or whatever):

```
template<class T>
class Mass
{
    T _kg;
public:
    Mass(T kg) : _kg(kg) {}
    Mass(double lb) : _kg(lb/2.2046) {} // ho no!
    T kg() const { return _kg }
};
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebc4e28d0f82cd33).

This doesn't work since `T` can be `double`.

### Make semantic obvious

The solution is as simple as naming thing. This is particularly true for functions taking multiple arguments of the same type. Imagine someday you read some obscure old code and you stumble upon:

```
draw(2.6, 2.8, 54.1, 26.0); // draw selection
```

What does it do? Well, obviously it draws something. It takes four double parameters, it may be a rectangle. You take some time, go see the declaration of `draw`, find its doc, ... and figure out it draws a rectangle given two points. It could have been one point, a width and a height, it could have been many things.

In another life, imagine instead of the line above you found:

```
draw(Point{2.6, 2.8}, Point{54.1, 26.0}); // draw selection
```

Is it not *obvious* now?

### Making semantic obvious in our mass case

```
struct pounds { double value; operator double() const { return value; } };

template<class T>
class Mass
{
    T _kg;
public:
    Mass(T kg) : _kg(kg) {}
    Mass(pounds lb) : _kg(lb/2.2046) {}
    T kg() const { return _kg; }
};
```

The user can *obviously* use it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    Mass<double> one_litter_of_water(pounds{2.2046});
    std::cout << "1 L of water is: " << one_litter_of_water.kg() << " kg\n";
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e88beabe508bc318).

### Improvements

Now that you've named your semantics, you can go further and provide a rich overload set:

```
struct unit { double value; operator double() const { return value; } };
struct pounds : unit {};
struct stones : unit {};
struct grams  : unit {};

template<class T>
class Mass
{
    T _kg;
public:
    Mass(T kg) : _kg(kg) {}
    Mass(pounds lb) : _kg(lb/2.2046) {}
    Mass(stones st) : _kg(st/0.1575) {}
    Mass(grams  g)  : _kg(g/1000.0) {}
    T kg() const { return _kg; }
};
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bfb25be61d5571b).

This is important to note that the logic (unit conversion) is still in the implementation of `Mass`; `pounds`, `stone`, *etc.* are just names: semantics. In this context it may not matter (one kilogram will stay ~0.16 stones for a long time), but in general you should prefer to encapsule those implementation details at the same place.

Comment: you must have stolen the `draw` with `Point`s example from my slides on "Why is it of major importance to give proper names to stuff", that I actually never showed anybody :P nice answer